# Why do I have different "pip list" resources in the same environment, depending on which tmux session I am currently in?

Tags: pip, tmux

I have a virtual environment within which I work with PyTorch and have opened several tmux sessions. Today I noticed that, when running `pip list` in one of the tmux sessions, I get no installed torch-version at all. In another tmux session, I get e.g. torch 2.1.2 and other installed packages.

Does somebody know what the mistake here is and how to fix it without having to create a new virtual environment?

Kind regards

PS: In this environment I also have to first load my python version via `module load...` before being able to use things like `pip list`. Otherwise I get an error "home/python_env/python: error  while loading shared libraries: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file" (see also my comment below)

Comment: 1st, check they're the same virtual environments: `type -a python pip` , `python --version` , `pip --version`

Comment: for ```type -a python pip``` I get two paths each for python and pip (one /usr/bin/ and the other /home/virtualenv/bin) ; ```python --version``` and ```pip--version``` throw "error while loading shared libraries" because I didn't do ```module load python``` yet ; after that I get versions for pip and python

Comment: I somehow managed to now get three paths each for python and pip with ```type -a python pip```, can somebody help me understand how this keeps happening and if I can "fuse" these different versions somehow?

Comment: You have 3 different Pythons in `$PATH` (some could be symlinks, esp. on MacOS, but that you should investigate yourself). There is no way to combine them, only uninstall or at least remove from `$PATH`. The most recommended way to work with projects is Python virtual environments instead of churning global installations with unrelated packages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! My problem is that it happened within my virtual environment and I do not know how I managed to do this. I would like to understand it so it does not happen again...

Comment: Python virtual environments work by prepending `…/venv/bin/` at the bery beginning of the `$PATH` so that unqualified (without explicit path) `python` and `pip` run from that venv. The only thing that could spoil venv is shell alias that runs `python` from a different path — aliases are evaluated before commands.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is what happens when I use "module load Python..." and then load the other python into the venv. Do you know by chance how I can change it back?

Comment: I suspect `module load Python` is from `zsh` and I know very little about it. 30 years of `bash` :-)